# Downloading Sass with Node.js and the git Bash command line

Tags: html, css, sass

I am having trouble downloading Sass in the command line.
I'm using Studio Code for my text editor. I need to know how to download it and add it to a website project.

This is what I have done so far in the command line

```
$ node --version
v17.8.0

$ npm --version
8.5.5

$ npm i sass

up to date, audited 18 packages in 2s

2 packages are looking for funding run 'npm fund' for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

$ npm start
```

> ```
> sass-app@1.0.0 startsass./sass/index.scss./css/style.css
> ```

```
'sass.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

**Here is the json package file.**

```
{
"name": "sass-app",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
   "test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1",
   "start": "sass./sass/index.scss./css/style.css"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {"sass": "^1.49.9"
 }
}
```

Comment: Put a space after `sass` in your `start` script.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing spaces in your `start` script to separate the program name from the arguments.

```
"start": "sass./sass/index.scss./css/style.css"
```

should be

```
"start": "sass ./sass/index.scss ./css/style.css"
```